# Is using `sync` in Rhino sufficient to synchronize access to shared objects and eliminate races?

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, synchronized, rhino

I have a sample of JavaScript (Rhino) code that uses the `sync` feature to synchronize access to a JavaScript array.

When I include the line `task.shift = sync(task.shift)`, replacing the shift method with a synchronized version of itself on `task`, it seems to eliminate the race. Without it, I sometimes see output like this (4 is duplicated, 7 is absent):

```
1
3
2
4
4
5
6
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

But I am not confident that using `sync` in this way has eliminated the race condition. It seems to have done so for the few tests I have run, but is there a way to be sure?

```
// range 0 .. n-1
function range(n) {
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        out.push(i);
    }
    return out;
}

var tasks = [
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 1; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 2; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 3; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 4; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 5; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 6; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 7; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 8; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 9; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 10; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 11; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 12; sleep 1"],
    ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 13; sleep 1"]
];


function n_workers(n, tasks) {
    var tasks = tasks;
    // synchronize shift method. Is it sufficient?
    tasks.shift = sync(tasks.shift);
    range(n).map(function () {
        var obj = {
            run : function () {
                while (true) {
                    var task = tasks.shift();
                    // we can still shift when the queue is empty
                    // we just get a bogus item
                    if (task === undefined) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var pb = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(task);
                    pb.inheritIO();
                    var process = pb.start();
                    process.waitFor();
                }
            }
        };

        var thread = java.lang.Thread(obj);
        thread.start();
    });
}

n_workers(3, tasks);
```